# What is the death toll attributed to US internment of Japanese-Americans during WWII?

Tags: united-states, world-war-two

We know that Spanish internment camps in Cuba at the start of 20th century were pretty horrific in terms of death toll.

What was the death toll attributed to US [internment camps for Japanese-Americans](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internment_of_Japanese_Americans) during WWII?

(Specifically, deaths attributed to internment, NOT just deaths that occurred in the camp but would presumably occur just as well without it.)

Comment: How do you define "attributed to internment". Are you only interested in people who died by violence or those who were unlawfully killed by the camp's guards or what?

Comment: @Richard - People who can be realistically assumed to have died **because** they were interned (killed by guards, or died from reasons cause by the internment like hunger/higher illness/mortality). E.g. take average mortality for a population of that size and demographics in those years, and compare to actual mortality for interned people. I'm pretty sure research on the topic ought to exist

Answer (score 13):

In terms of direct death-count relating to the incarceration itself, there are reports of approximately a dozen deaths as a result of [shootings](http://www.pbs.org/childofcamp/history/timeline.html) (during various escape attempts) as well as several children and elderly people dying as a result of "inadequate health care".

In terms of *general longevity*, there have been numerous reports into the long-term results of incarceration, the general concensus being that internees had nearly a double incidence of heart disease and stress-related mortality outcomes:

> "Survey information found former internees had a 2.1 greater risk of
>   cardiovascular disease, cardiovascular mortality, and premature death
>   than did a non-interned counterpart. California Nisei-age individuals,
>   the proxy for internment, died 1.6 years earlier than Hawaiians who
>   represented non-interned status. I concluded traumatic stress has
>   life-long consequences even in the presence of efficacious coping
>   strategies."
>
> <sub><sub>"**The Experience of Injustice: Health Consequences of the Japanese American Internment",** Gwendolyn M. Jensen, 1997.</sub></sub>

Overall, it's worth stressing that these were not death camps, People were not randomly dying of minor ailments, maltreatment, overwork or starvation. The crude [rate of mortality](http://inconvenienthistory.com/archive/2009/volume_1/number_1/in_defense_of_internment.php) within the camps was approximately 1.5% and essentially the same as non-interned civilians [of the same period](http://www.nber.org/vital-stats-books/VSUS_1937_1.CV.pdf).

Comment: Was there an attempt to quantify that risk increase to net mortality vs. percentages? While not direct result, it's still valid data, even if causality is harder to establish.

Comment: @DVK - The accepted figure is that each internee lost 1.6 years of life.

Comment: @DVK - To complicate matters, you have to take into account that young men who were interned actually had a lower mortality (since there weren't any Germans shooting at them) and internees also received long-term healthcare benefits and various windfall compensation schemes.

Comment: To complicate things even more, Japanese-American men had the option of enlisting in the military instead of being interned.

Comment: @Richard Actually, there were  for some. Only there were not Japaneese shooting at them. Because they were sent to European theatre.  I watched some TV document about Japanese-American unit in WW2. They were send as diversion against some hill in Italy and took it despite heavy loses (they were not informed that they are diversion).